# Angular светофор и машинки

Tags: angular, компоненты

Нужно сделать светофор и машинки, которые будут ездить в зависимости от цвета светофора. По клику на цвет его можно включить(клацаем на зеленый - включается зеленый). Создал компонент светофора. Смену света светофора сделал через таймер. Создал компонент машинки в котором с помощью state и animate сделал анимацию(не до конца). Вот не пойму как связать компонент светофора и машинки.

```js
import {Component, OnInit, Injectable, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {animate, state, style, transition, trigger} from "@angular/animations";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import {Car} from '../car'
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
@Component({
  animations: [
    trigger('lightGreen', [
      state('greenOff', style({
        background: 'grey'
      })),
      state('green', style({
        background: 'green'
      })),
      transition('green <=> greenOff', animate('0ms'))
    ]),
    trigger('lightRed', [
      state('redOff', style({
        background: 'grey'
      })),
      state('red', style({
        background: 'red'
      })),
      transition('red <=> redOff', animate('0ms'))
    ])
  ],
  selector: 'app-traffic-light',
  templateUrl: './traffic-light.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./traffic-light.component.sass']
})

export class TrafficLightComponent implements OnInit {
  greenOff = false;
  redOff = true;

  constructor() {}

  get stateGreen() {
    return this.greenOff ? 'greenOff' : 'green'
  }

  get stateRed() {
    return this.redOff ? 'redOff' : 'red'
  }

  timeGreen: number = 15;
  timeRed: number = 5;
  timeLeft = this.timeGreen;
  interval;


  ngOnInit() {
    this.startTimer();
  }

  startTimer() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      console.log(this.timeLeft);
      if (this.timeLeft > this.timeRed) {
        this.redOff = true;
        this.greenOff = false;
        this.timeLeft--;

      } else if (this.timeLeft > 1 && this.timeLeft <= this.timeRed) {
        this.greenOff = true;
        this.redOff = false;
        this.timeLeft--;
      } else {
        this.timeLeft = this.timeGreen;
      }
    }, 1000)
  }

  turnGreen() {
    console.log('change to green');
    this.timeLeft = this.timeGreen;
  }

  turnRed() {
    console.log('change to red');
    this.timeLeft = this.timeRed;
  }
}
```

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Injectable, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { Car } from '../car';
import {AppComponent} from "../app.component";
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {animate, state, style, transition, trigger} from "@angular/animations";
import {TrafficLightComponent} from "../traffic-light/traffic-light.component";

@Component({
  animations: [
    trigger('myState', [
      state('stop', style({
        marginLeft: '0'
      })),
      state('move', style({
        marginLeft: '100%'
      })),
      transition('move => stop', animate(0 + 'ms')),
      transition('stop => move', animate(4000 + 'ms')),
    ])

  ],
  selector: 'app-car',
  templateUrl: './car.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./car.component.sass']
})

@Injectable()
export class CarComponent implements OnInit {

  car: Car = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Merz',
    score: 20
    // urlPath: '../assets/images/car.png'
  };

  constructor() { }
  move;
  stop;
  timerId;
  x:number;
  get stateName() {
    return this.move ? 'move' : 'stop'
  }

  toggle() {
    this.move = !this.move;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // this.run();\
  }

  hz(x:number){
    this.x = x;
    console.log(this.x);
  }

}
```

Comment: а зачем вы декорируете компонент с `Injectable`? :)

Comment: к тому же анимации биндятся в шаблонах, на коде одних компонентов каши не сваришь